# Show what queries ran in the TRN files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of TRN files provided by the third party. My question is is there anyway to see what queries actually runs inside the TRN files? I know apexSQL log could review this. Here is my query so far. Please help me out.

```
SELECT so.*
    , Operation
    , [Transaction SID]
    , SUSER_NAME([Transaction SID]) AS [LoginName]
FROM fn_dump_dblog(NULL, NULL, 'DISK', 1
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak0'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak1'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak2'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak3'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak4'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak5'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak6'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak7'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak8'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak9'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak10'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak11'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak12'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak13'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak14'
    ,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak15'
    , 'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak16'
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) blog
INNER JOIN sys.partitions sp
    ON blog.PartitionId = sp.partition_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects so
    ON so.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE blog.Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
    AND so.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE';
```

Comment: So, you're interested in rows that were deleted?

Comment: In SQL server transaction logs (.log files) aren't like web server logs. They don't log the queries/batches that people and processes submit, they log snapshots of database pages before- and after- changes occur. Likewise, .trn files are just backups of the .log files and don't store query/batch information. Have a read through [The Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server) for a mile-high overview.